# CM13 Transparent lockscreen not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-one, cyanogen-os

I have oneplus one with the latest built of cyanogen13.1 but here is a problem, my live lockscreen which shows blur background of the recent app that is opened is not working. I just showing the regular wallpaper on the lockscreen. I tried everything but non of it seems to work.